# How can I read partially entered text from bash?

Tags: c, bash, readline

When I enter some text and then <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>, the partially entered text appears in the reverse search prompt:

```
> hello[Ctrl+R]
(reverse-i-search)`': hello
```

I'm looking to write a replacement for reverse search. The shortcut can be re-bound to run a different program, for example:

```
bind -x '"\C-R":"echo test"'
> hello[Ctrl+R]
test
> hello
```

How can I access the partially entered command/text `hello` from a program I bind <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> to?

Tab completion sets `COMP_WORDS`, `COMP_LINE` etc. I'm looking for something similar, ideally directly accessible by a C/C++ executable.

Answer (score 3):

Found what I'm after here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82716/54030

The environment variable [READLINE_LINE](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-READLINE_005fLINE) can be read and even modified:

```
bind -x '"\C-R":"echo cmd=$READLINE_LINE"'
> hello[Ctrl+R]
cmd=hello

bind -x '"\C-R":"READLINE_LINE=replaced; READLINE_POINT=8"'
> hello[Ctrl+R]
... becomes
> replaced
```

`READLINE_POINT` is used to set the cursor position.